# register_setting() vs add_option()

Tags: options, settings-api

Im creating my first WordPress plugin. I added a custom function on plugin activation hook where I create new rows in `wp_options` table by using `add_option()` function. Now, I want to create a custom settings API page, and I noticed that people use `register_setting()` function, then render those functions and etc, but as I know, it creates row inside `wp_options` table? So do I still need to hook `admin_init` and call those `register_setting()` if I did `add_option()` before?

Answer (score 3):

> So do I still need to hook `admin_init` and call those `register_setting()` if I did `add_option()` before?

Yes. You need.

You may add `add_option` to set the default value.
Another call to `add_option` will do nothing.
However, the idea of `register_setting()` is more than just `add_option()`.

Each setting has the context page such as (general, reading, writing, media, some-page-that-you-defined, ...) and can have the callback function where you can do action on your data.

For more info check the [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API).

---

Someone may think the Settings API is a big mess. BTW, this is what you can read from the WordPress core.

```
File: wp-admin/includes/template.php
2: /**
3:  * Template WordPress Administration API.
4:  *
5:  * A Big Mess. Also some neat functions that are nicely written.
```

*(there is also part of the settings API in **wp-includes/option.php** )*

On the other side, an [example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) from the codex can help you start up fast.

However when working with settings you need to dig deep and cover the possible errors — so you need to understand how it works perfectly.

This may be hard for the WordPress programmers that start writing the first plugins. It may take days.

In WordPress 4.7 we had updates to the Settings API, but this doesn't negotiate the fact that the Settings API may be leveled up in the future.

If I recall, it is hard to choose the different HTML elements when you create sections for instance:

```
File: wp-admin/includes/template.php
1286: function do_settings_sections( $page ) {
1287:   global $wp_settings_sections, $wp_settings_fields;
1288: 
1289:   if ( ! isset( $wp_settings_sections[$page] ) )
1290:       return;
1291: 
1292:   foreach ( (array) $wp_settings_sections[$page] as $section ) {
1293:       if ( $section['title'] )
1294:           echo "<h2>{$section['title']}</h2>\n";
1295: 
1296:       if ( $section['callback'] )
1297:           call_user_func( $section['callback'], $section );
1298: 
1299:       if ( ! isset( $wp_settings_fields ) || !isset( $wp_settings_fields[$page] ) || !isset( $wp_settings_fields[$page][$section['id']] ) )
1300:           continue;
1301:       echo '<table class="form-table">';
1302:       do_settings_fields( $page, $section['id'] );
1303:       echo '</table>';
1304:   }
1305: }
```

As I see the problem with the *Settings API* — this API is old.

---

What may be the possible improvement. 
Pseudo-language. You just define your form like this via the Settings API

```
   ---
   name: cool-settings.php
   style: default            
   ---
   textfield: First Name|first-name
   textfield: Last Name|last-name
   textarea: About Yourself|about
   image: Your Image|image|(.gif|.jpg|.jpeg|.png)
```

I saw this syntax from Jekyll.